# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'indim'

Tags: python, pybrain

I'm working with the package 'pybrain' and trying to build a neural network that will recognize images. The part of analyzing the photo is working very well, but as one who is new to pybrain- I'm not used to working with it. Somehow I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'indim'
```

I've tried to solve this problem like a day or so and still doesn't get it. here's part of my code:

```
target=np.array([[0],[1]])
input=getNumberOfImages("photosAfterAverage/",1,2)
ds=SupervisedDataSet(72,1)
ds.setField('target',target)
ds.setField('input',input)
print ds.data
net=buildNewNetwork(72,76,1)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
```

Assume that input is a 2 dimensional containg each cell 72 cells.

Edit: As requested, the whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Eytan\Desktop\Mah\Kids_Painting\pyBrainDiffrenceBetween5GradeAnd2Grade.py", line 53, in <module>
        trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
      File "C:\Python27\pybrain\supervised\trainers\backprop.py", line 35, in __init__
        self.setData(dataset)
      File "C:\Python27\pybrain\supervised\trainers\trainer.py", line 22, in setData
        assert dataset.indim == self.module.indim
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'indim'
```

It may be helpful to point out that the following code is working:

```
net=buildNetwork(2,500,1)
ds=SupervisedDataSet(2,1)
input=array([[0,1],[1,3434],[34,65],[40,56]])
target=array([[0],[1],[0],[1]])
ds.setField('input',input)
ds.setField('target',target)
print ds.data
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
```

Thanks very much for answering, I found the problem- the right function that should have been used is buildNetwork instead of buildNewNetwork.

Comment: There is no `indim` in your code. Please provide the stack trace. That makes it a lot easier to reason about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like dataset has to be sent as a [keyword argument](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/supervised/trainers/backprop.py#L16). Try,

```
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, dataset=ds)
```

Comment: Thanks, But no that's not the problem, it didn't fix it.